# change a line with awk

Tags: bash, awk

Im trying to make a substitution of a single line in a file with awk, for example

changing this:

```
e1 is (on)

e2 is (off)
```

to:

```
e1 is (on)

e2 is (on)
```

use command:

```
awk '/e2/{gsub(/off/, "on")};{print}' ~/Documents/Prueba > ~/Documents/Prueba
```

this makes the substitution but the file ends blank!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Another answer, using a different tool (sed, and the -i (in place) flag)

```
sed -i '/e2/ s/off/on/' ~/Documents/Prueba
```

Comment: This does not work on OSX :) https://stackoverflow.com/q/4247068/282601

Answer (score 25):

Your awk is correct, however you are redirecting to the same file as your original. This is causing the original file to be overwritten before it has been read. You'll need to redirect the output to a different file.

```
awk '/e2/{gsub(/off/, "on")};{print}' ~/Documents/Prueba > ~/Documents/Prueba.new
```

Rename Prueba.new afterwards if necessary.

Comment: +1. Emphasis on "the original file [is] overwritten *before* it has been read"

Answer (score 7):

As explained by the other answers and in the question "[Why reading and writing the same file through I/O redirection results in an empty file in Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895981/why-reading-and-writing-the-same-file-through-i-o-redirection-results-in-an-empt)", the shell redirections destroy your input file before it is read.

To solve that problem without explicitly resorting to temporary files, have a look at the [sponge](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/moreutils/sponge.1.en.html) command from the [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) collection.

```
awk '/e2/{gsub(/off/, "on")};{print}' ~/Documents/Prueba | sponge ~/Documents/Prueba
```

Alternatively, if GNU awk is installed on your system, you can use the [in place extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html).

```
gawk -i inplace '/e2/{gsub(/off/, "on")};{print}' ~/Documents/Prueba
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `cat` to read the file first, then use `pipe` to redirect to stdout, then read with `awk` from stdin:

```
cat ~/Documents/Prueba | awk '/e2/{gsub(/off/, "on")};{print}' - > ~/Documents/Prueba
```

I believe the dash `-` is optional, since you're only reading stdin.

Some interesting documentation: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Naming-Standard-Input.html

Answer (score 1):

You cannot redirect the output to the same file as the input file. Choose another file name.

The **`>`** will empty your file at the first place.

---

You can try [sponge](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sponge).