# Removing the following characters after a pattern in a text file in Unix

Tags: regex, shell, unix, sed, awk

I have a text file which has the following lines:

```
Customer Details Report - A03_2014-01-04_09-00-09.txt
DemandResetFailureReport_2014-01-04_11-00-08.txt
ExcessiveMissingReadsReport_2014-01-04_09-00-11.txt
LipaBillingSumCheckReport_2014-01-04_11-00-08.txt
LipaUsageBillingReport_2014-01-04_12-55-06.txt
```

I want to run a command in UNIX (say, `sed`) which will edit the contents of the text file as:

```
Customer Details Report 
DemandResetFailureReport
ExcessiveMissingReadsReport
LipaBillingSumCheckReport
LipaUsageBillingReport
```

I came across some commands such as `sed '/^pattern/ d'` to remove all lines after pattern. But where is the text file specified in the command?

Comment: BTW `sed '/^pattern/d'` removes all lines having the word `pattern` at the beginning. If you use a regex instead of `^pattern`, it removes all lines matching that pattern.

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` you can set `-` and `_` as field separator (`-F[-_]`) and print the first block (`{print $1}`):

```
$ awk -F"[-_]" '{print $1}' file
Customer Details Report 
DemandResetFailureReport
ExcessiveMissingReadsReport
LipaBillingSumCheckReport
LipaUsageBillingReport
```

Comment: OP doesn't want to have `_2014` in output.

Comment: Solved, just left the `awk` version. Thanks, Kent 2014 :)

Comment: better make sure you quote the -F pattern. If you have a file named "_", or if you have the nullglob option enabled, you're in trouble.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -o '^[^-_]*'
```

outputs:

```
Customer Details Report 
DemandResetFailureReport
ExcessiveMissingReadsReport
LipaBillingSumCheckReport
LipaUsageBillingReport
```

Answer (score 1):

I always use perl -pi, as follows:

```
$ perl -pi -e 's/[-_].*//' file
$ cat file
Customer Details Report 
DemandResetFailureReport
ExcessiveMissingReadsReport
LipaBillingSumCheckReport
LipaUsageBillingReport
```

If a backup of the original is needed, specify a suffix for the backup file, for example:

```
$ perl -pi.bak -e 's/[-_].*//' file
```

See also the following topic on editing files in place: [sed edit file in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12696125/sed-edit-the-file-in-place)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `sed -i 's/[-_].*//' file.txt`. Your text file (`file.txt`) must be passed as argument (I chose that way) or on standard input (`sed 's/[-_].*//' < file.txt > file2.txt`), but that way you could not edit it in-place (`-i`). Be sure not to use `sed … <file.txt >file.txt` as [that will delete your `file.txt` contents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1895981/2157640).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -ri 's/( -|_).*//' file
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk`

```
awk '{sub(/[-_].*/,x)}1' file
Customer Details Report
DemandResetFailureReport
ExcessiveMissingReadsReport
LipaBillingSumCheckReport
LipaUsageBillingReport
```

This removes what you does not want and print the rest.